# Android Studio Debug Watch pane is missing

Tags: android-studio

OK this is really stupid. I have no idea what happened to the debug watch frame in Android Studio.  I have 1.5.1 of Studio.
Is there some secret knowledge from intellij to show it.

Answer (score 35):

Here's the icon that @jamesldurham referred to:

[image: Restore Layout icon]

Thanks James! I think it would have taken me a long time to find that :/

Comment: Its on the bottom left! :)

Comment: As an update to this question that's relevant for Android Studio 3.0 and above, the Watch panel is now integrated in the Variables panel.

Answer (score 8):

Ok I with some help there is a button debug menu that looks like a desaturated American flag that when pressed brings it back.

The tool tip will show restore layout.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to restore the entire debug layout, the below image is pointing to the "restore watches view" button. It is in the upper right corner of the debug console and looks like a pair of green shaded glasses over a window.

The button to its left restrores the "Threads" view, and to the right restores the "Variables" view.

[image: Watch pane button]

Answer (score 3):

Unlike previous *IDE*s the `Watch` panel is now totally integrated into the `Variables` panel
And there is no ***watch the variable*** option neither in the popup when right clicking on a variable.

The only option is to select the varaible that needs to be watched and drag and drop it onto the `Variables` panel.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have the **Frames** tab selected instead of **Development**, in the left bottom section.